# Debug IOS xamarin app on windows

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is there any way that's I can debug IOS xamarin app from windows directly to iPhone using USB or any other way .
I tried to use macOS Sierra emulator 
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

Try this one. I think you should read the xamarin documentation